# How do I convert a [Raw].load string to a DNS layer? (using python and scapy)

Tags: python, dns

I have a school project, in which I need to create a DNS server.
(I can only use scapy, no other libs. I have python 2.7 32bit and I use a wired ethernet cable).
If I do have the requested domain name in my database, I just send it back to my client.
If I don't have it, I need to ask 8.8.8.8 (or another server) and then send the response to the client, then store the answer in my cache. Sending the answer works perfectly, but storing the information is the problem.
8.8.8.8's answer packets are sent to me this way: `Ether()/IP()/UDP()/Raw()`. In order to send the answer to the client I just change the IP and UDP's addresses and ports and just send the Raw layer above them and it works. But, the [Raw].load of the answer packet is encoded in a way I don't understand (and `.decode('utf-8'/16/32)` didn't work). 
For example :

```
###[ Raw ]###
        load      = '\x007\x81\x80\x00\x01\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03www\x03aeo
\x03com\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\xc0\x0c\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00/\xab\x00\x04\xa5\xa0
\x0f\x14\xc0\x0c\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00/\xab\x00\x04\xa5\xa0\r\x14'
```

I found out that it may be the (str(answerpacket[DNS]) version of it but when I try to convert it back to [DNS] (using `(DNS(answerpkt[Raw].load)`) it gives me the following error:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scapy\base_classes.py", line 198, in __cal
l__
    i.__init__(*args, **kargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scapy\packet.py", line 80, in __init__
    self.dissect(_pkt)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scapy\packet.py", line 575, in dissect
    s = self.do_dissect(s)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scapy\packet.py", line 549, in do_dissect
    s,fval = f.getfield(self, s)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scapy\layers\dns.py", line 145, in getfiel
d
    rr,p = self.decodeRR(name, s, p)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scapy\layers\dns.py", line 123, in decodeR
R
    rr = DNSRR("\x00"+ret+s[p:p+rdlen])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scapy\base_classes.py", line 198, in __cal
l__
    i.__init__(*args, **kargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scapy\packet.py", line 80, in __init__
    self.dissect(_pkt)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scapy\packet.py", line 575, in dissect
    s = self.do_dissect(s)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scapy\packet.py", line 549, in do_dissect
    s,fval = f.getfield(self, s)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scapy\fields.py", line 509, in getfield
    return s[l:], self.m2i(pkt,s[:l])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scapy\layers\dns.py", line 177, in m2i
    s = inet_ntop(family, s)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scapy\pton_ntop.py", line 66, in inet_ntop

    return inet_ntoa(addr)
NameError: global name 'inet_ntoa' is not defined
```

So my question is- how do I convert that '\x0x0x0x0' string to a DNS layer that I can take information from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug in scapy that's triggered on Windows machines (http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.security.scapy.general/4733).  Unfortunately, it looks like the bugfix isn't in the latest versions of scapy.

The recommendation in that post is to edit the scapy source directly.  In your case, edit `C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scapy\pton_ntop.py` and change line 66 from:

```
return inet_ntoa(addr)
```

to:

```
return socket.inet_ntoa(addr)
```